# How to Export a Report in Microsoft Power BI with Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: report, powerbi

I am developing a system in **Asp.net MVC 5**. The system reports are in **Microsoft Power BI**. The user needs to export the report to an Excel file.

Does anybody know how to apply or develop a button or a Visual in Microsoft Power Bi reports to export the particular report to an Excel file when it is published?

The Export icon is available when the report is in In Power BI account / Dashboard as below.
[image]

But when the report is published and when the user views the report through MVC application, there is no way to export data to a ***.xlsx*** file or **.csv** file(as shown below).Export and Pin icons are missing. I need a method or any special widget which can do that work. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two options to export to Excel

1. [Export Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-visualization-export-data)
2. [Analyze in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-analyze-in-excel)

However, neither of these will allow you to export an entire report including visuals. This is currently one of the more irritating limitations of Power BI.

There are a number of [ideas on the Power BI forums](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas?query=export%20to%20excel) that are related to this. Please add your vote and comments to the ones that are most relevant to you.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you say. Thank you @Alexis I have already tried them. But did not work with me. I have a system developed in Asp.net MVC 5. I am giving the report link in the application. When it is given, the three dots in Power BI account which allows you to export data is disappeared. That's where my problem is. Anyway, I have added some pictures to my above question to make the problem more clear.